# Core Data fetch is not "fault" at first, but becomes "fault"

Tags: ios, core-data, fault

I have a singleton Data Manager that has this method:

```
-(NSArray*)fetchItems
{
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


NSError *error2;
NSFetchRequest *itemFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[itemFetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[itemFetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];


NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"order"
                                                               ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[itemFetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSArray *fetchedItems = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:itemFetchRequest error:&error2];


return fetchedItems;


}
```

I then create some views based on the core data objects like this:

```
self.items = [dataManager fetchItems];
for (Item *item in self.items) { //Item is the NSManagedObject subclass
    ItemView *itemView = [[ItemView alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame ];

    [itemView layoutWithData:item];
    [self.someView addSubview:itemView];

}
```

The ItemView's data gets set like this:

```
- (void)layoutWithData:(Item*)_data {
self.data = _data;

NSLog(@"ItemView data: %@", self.data); //not "fault" at this point
...

UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setImage:data.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn.frame = aFrame;
[self addSubview:btn];

}
```

At this point, the ItemView's data is defined and is not "fault". However, when a tap is detected like this:

```
- (void)tapDetected:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"TAP: %@", self.data); //fault - see below
[self.delegate itemTapped:self.data];
}
```

I get something like this:

```
TAP: <Item: 0x879ce40> (entity: Item; id: 0x8798310 <x-coredata://8BE9ABFE-7C63-4ADD-9AD1-62B81C5AFF66/Item/p66> ; data: <fault>)
```

Why is the data "non-fault" at first and then "fault" later when I tap the ItemView and how can I fix it? This has been killing me all day...

EDIT: using this code I can confirm that the data is not a fault in the layoutWithData method, but is a fault in the tapDetected method:

```
NSLog(@"is fault? %i", self.data.isFault);
```

Why would it turn into a fault???

Comment: Have you tried overriding `-willTurnIntoFault` on `Item` and seeing if it gives you into clues as to why it's being turned into a fault?

Comment: @CarlVeazey Yes I can override that method, and indeed I can log to the console that it's being turned into a fault, but I don't know how to get any clues from that.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the method and see who's calling it?

Comment: According to the docs this method is invoked automatically by the Core Data framework before the receiver is converted to a fault. So the question is how do you convert away from being a fault?

Comment: I don't think you have control over it at that point - but perhaps you can identify what is causing it to turn back into a fault, and avert that condition. I'm assuming that the fact that it's become a fault is causing some performance issues when the fault fires again?

Comment: The problem is that I need the data from the Item object. When I try to access self.data.title for example, I get null because self.data is a fault. I need self.data to be the actual Item object instead of a fault.

Comment: Maybe I completely misunderstand how faulting works? Shouldn't the fault fire when you access the attribute?

Comment: That's what I thought. But self.data is still a fault even after I access self.data.title... NSLog(@"TAP: %@", self.data.title); //(null)
    NSLog(@"is fault? %i", self.data.isFault); //1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16068/discussion-between-carl-veazey-and-soleil)

Answer (score 0):

It may not really be a problem, but a fault that means that the data hasn't been read yet.  Try doing the following before the fetch:

```
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];
```

That way the data will be completely read.

See
[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046291/core-data-fault)