# FetchRequst issue with data fault

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

When I was inserting data to one entity of CoreData, All the rows are inserted successfully(Saved).

But when I try to fetch the data using FetchRequest, Only one row of data is coming even if number of rows inserted are 3 or 4 or anything(more than 1).
   Remaining rows are not getting fetched. And when I print fetch results,

It says - **Error**

```
0:<EquipmentDetails: 0x6000000bad60> 
(entity: EquipmentDetails; id: 0xd000000000040000 
coredata:/EquipmentDetails/p1> **data:fault>)**
```

I didn't get what was going in backend of core data?

### code for Insertion

```
func insertEqipToLocalDb()
    {
        let mobileNo : String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "phoneNumber")!

        let equipDetailsItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "EquipmentDetails", into:managedObjContext) as! EquipmentDetails

        for (index,item) in array_IDEquip.enumerated()
        {
            equipDetailsItem.mobileNumber = mobileNo
            equipDetailsItem.type = array_typeEquip[index]
            equipDetailsItem.name = array_nameEquip[index]
            equipDetailsItem.startDate = array_sDateEquip[index]
            equipDetailsItem.endDate = array_eDateEquip[index]
            equipDetailsItem.equpID = Int16(item)
            equipDetailsItem.serviceDatesStr = array_serviceDateEquip[index]
        }
        do
        {
            try managedObjContext.save()
            UserDefaults.standard.set("AlreadyInstalled", forKey: "statusInstallation")
        }

        catch
        {
            Exception.insertExceptionDetails(errorMsg: error as NSError, context: managedObjContext)
        }
    }
```

//code for fetching

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
    let entity =    NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName:"EquipmentDetails", in: managedObjContext)
    request.entity = entity
    do
    {
        let fetchResults  = try managedObjContext.fetch(request)

        for r in fetchResults
        {
            typeEquipArray.append((r as AnyObject).value(forKey:  "type") as! String)
        }
    }
catch let error as NSError
{
    Exception.insertExceptionDetails(errorMsg: error, context: managedObjContext)
}
```

Comment: Example of your code?

Comment: Based on how you're reading the data, I would say...oops, no code, so no-one can say much at all

Comment: @Socraties Srikanth Please update your question with the required code!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Core Data Fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046291/core-data-fault)

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
let equipDetailsItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "EquipmentDetails", into:managedObjContext) as! EquipmentDetails
```

You create **one** instance. In the loop that follows, you set values for the `type`, `name`, etc properties over and over again **on that same instance**. Then you save changes, which include just that one object. If you want a difference instance of `EquipmentDetails` for each pass through the loop, you need to create the instance inside the loop.

The "fault" message is not an error unless you tried to access the property values and found that they were not present. It's part of how Core Data works. See the answer that Harshal Valanda linked in the comments for more detail.